# What OpenStreetMap tile servers to use for WordPress Plugin Development?

Tags: wordpress, openstreetmap

i was wondering what Open Street Map tile server to use for a WordPress plugin i am currently working on. I know there is some latency sometimes on the default one and there are some legal stuff that comes to it too. Does anyone have experience on this and could share knowledge? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "default" tiles operated by the OSMF are *not* for heavy use. These servers only have limited capacity and run on donated resources. Using them in a popular WordPress plugin will get you banned very soon. See the [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) for more details.

[Alternatives](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/#alternative-openstreetmap-tile-providers):

- [Paid-for tile servers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services)
- [Your own tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/)